# Is there a JQuery API for assigning the month name based on the number.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am working on SharePoint List, fetching the date from the list, which is generally in this format : 2013-03-25.

I have split the date and assigned to an variable.

Code.

```
var splitDate = resultRegionArr[x].NewsDate.split("-");
```

Now, i want to know if there is any Jquery API which returns me the string "March" on input of value "03" or splitDate[1].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why JQuery? It's simple enough to just create an array containing the month names and then the required name is the string at the array index `splitDate[1]`

Comment: @ElPedro Why jQuery? Everything is better with jQuery! It even do [math](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/jquery-math-finally-solved/)!!!

Comment: @some - Priceless :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April",
               "May", "June", "July", "August",
               "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var selectedMonthName = months[splitDate[1] - 1];
```

The `- 1` is optional. Depending on your input/output of `splitDate[1]`.

Comment: Thanks Dream Eater... Found this as the better way... Thanks gaian..:)

Answer (score 2):

try 
[www.datejs.com/](http://www.datejs.com/), for example:

```
alert(Date.parse('2013-03-25').toString('dd MMMM yyyy')) // 25 March 2013
```

this will give you what you want also bonus is other features!!